# Perl -s argument in division

Tags: perl

I'm working with a code where integers are divided:

```
$length = (-s $value1/$value2);
```

I'm getting an error that -s is an uninitialized value. What does that -s argument mean?

Comment: This would make more sense if it were `$length = (-s $value1) / $value2`. That is, it uses `$value1` as the name of a file, fetches its size, and divides that by `$value2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [-X](http://p3rl.org/-X):

> -s  File has nonzero size (returns size in bytes).

It doesn't seem to make any sense in this context. The division returns a number that is considered a file name which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @simbabque: Do you also have a script to generate a markdown link to a given perldoc page? ;-)

Comment: No, I press crtl+t, type `p foo` and copy it. I should start making scripts like that.

Answer (score 2):

The `-s` operator takes a filename and returns the size in bytes, or `undef` if an error occurs. One most commonly receives an error when the file doesn't exist, or when one has insufficient permissions. See [-X in perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Your `$value1/$value2` will return a number, and `-s` will then try to find a file in the current directory with that number as its name. That likely fails, so it returns `undef`.

Comment: *"The `-s` operator takes a filename and checks that the size is not zero, and returns the size in byte. "* It doesn't do any checks: it simply returns the size of the file, zero or otherwise

Comment: @Borodin better like this?